# How do I perform multiple, simple x y plots using multiple csv files?

Tags: r, csv, plot, ggplot2

I have multiple .csv files with frequency data for which I would like to produce multiple, simple x, y plots.  My data is already set up as a pseudo-histogram, with binwidth as the first column (x) and frequency as the second column (y).  I am attempting to create a loop that will load all the csv files to R, then plot x vs y for each file as a separate figure of type = "h".

I have created the following script:

```
#Load all *ZM.csv files
temp = list.files(pattern="*ZM.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))

#Plot
listcsvs <- lapply(temp, function(i) read.csv(i, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
names(listcsvs)<- temp
require(ggplot2)
for (i in 1:length(temp)){
  tmp <- melt(listcsvs[[i]], id.vars = "SL", measure.vars = c("Freq"))
  print(ggplot(tmp, aes(SL, value))) 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, fill = "black")
  ggtitle(names(listcsvs[i]))}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the script, the plots are blank; the x-axis is labeled "SL" and the y-axis is labeled "value", but no lines or points are plotted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure, you ask to print the figure before plotting any line or points. This should be something like `p <- ggplot(tmp, aes(SL, value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, fill = "black") +
  ggtitle(names(listcsvs[i])); print(p)`.

Comment: You might wanna rethink your current approach Heather. Instead of generating multiple plots you can take advantage of `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` to produce multiple graphs with ggplot. All you have to do is add a new column `id` to each dataframe with the number of the dataframe (e.g. 1 for dataframe1, 2 for dataframe2 and so on). Then you can combine all your dataframes with `do.call(rbind, dataframes)` and add `facet_wrap(~id, scales = "free")` to your plot to generate a single plot with subplots of each dataframe.